# Are purchases from the App store single or mulitple user licencing

Tags: mac-appstore

I have two Macs, I haven't bought any software on the App store yet.

If I wanted to buy lets say for example Pages and Numbers, would I be able to install that on one Mac or two macs? just like I can if I download an app from the iTunes app store I can install on both iPad and iPhone for the single price?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install apps on "any Mac you own or control"

http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html

About two thirds down the page

> If you are an individual acting in your personal capacity, you may
>   download and use an application from the Mac App Store (“Mac App Store
>   Product”) for personal, non-commercial use on any Apple-branded
>   products running Mac OS X (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control.

Comment: This also extends to at most five other people that you include in your "family sharing" group.

Answer (score 4):

You can install software from the MAS on multiple Macs. The only limitation in the EULA is that the software either is used by one person on multiple computers, or by multiple users on a single computer. So installing for multiple users on different computers would be a breach of the EULA (even though technically still possible if both computers are linked to the same Apple ID for purchases).

See http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html

EDIT: I'll have to ammend my answer even though it was already accepted. While the above is true for commercial use, for personal, non-commercial use in one and the same household on the other hand the above EULA restriction is not true.